# pytest_runtest_setup/call/teardown and @pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)

Tags: python, pytest

I'm having trouble understanding, in pytest, when (or why) i need to add the @pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True) tag to all my pytest_runtest_* calls.

basically, in conftest, i have implemented all of those calls to do do something before yeilding, and then doing something after, such as:

```
def pytest_runtest_call(item: Any) -> None:
    """ TODO: method docstring """

    item.session.test_info["on_case_number"] += 1
    pytest_log = getLogger("runtest")
    pytest_log.debug(f'= runtest started [{count_str(item.session.test_info)}]')
    outcome = yield
    setattr(item, "case_markers", item.own_markers)
    module_name, class_name, case_name = item.nodeid.split("::")
    trunk = item.session.test_info["items"][module_name]["classes"][class_name]
    try:
        # set a report attribute for each phase of a call, which can
        # be "setup", "call", "teardown"
        outcome.get_result()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        raise KeyboardInterrupt("Caught Keyboard Termination")
    except Exception as e:
        trunk["cases"][case_name]["passed"] = False
        _process_exception(e, item, pytest_log)
    pytest_log.debug(f'= runtest completed [{count_str(item.session.test_info)}]')
```

When I run a test case, this **never** gets called.  However, if I prepend to tag

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_call(item: Any) -> None:
...
```

It does get called.

But I was under the (probalby false) impression that a certain set of methods within pytest get called automagically if they are defined, including the pytest_runtest_* set (and in fact, pytest_collection_modifyitems for instance does get called eventually w/o the tag).

I'm confused as to why this is the case.  Or if I am just not getting/doing something correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of `pytest_runtest_call` is a *hook wrapper*, that is [a generator function which yields exactly once](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_hook_functions.html#hookwrapper-executing-around-other-hooks). See the line

```
    outcome = yield
```

Hook wrappers must use the `@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)` decorator or they won't be called at all.